# Error while installing prophet with azure function

Tags: python, azure-functions, prophet

I'm facing an error while installing prophet on azure.
In fact i want to install prophet module to run it in my azure function however this module requires others to install such as pystan and cython, when i added them to my requirements and deployed the whole project i receive this following error.
This error is shown even while running it locally.
Is there any way we can install these packages without having any errors ?
Or can we use the local conda environment and use it in azure ?

PS : i create a conda environment locally using python 3.8.13 and installed all packages, the function only works in this conda environment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V5Uz.png)

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happing because during deployment only function code maybe getting deployed and not the packages.

So, what you can do is containerize the function and then deploy it.

Thus build the function with all the modules then containerize it using docker and include the required packages in the docker build and then deploy them thus the packages will be present in the function.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-javascript#enable-continuous-deployment-to-azure) for Indepth explanation.